# Accessing IIS hosted website from web-server and other networked hosts

Tags: networking, dns, website, iis, windows-server-2016

I've set up a website on Internet Information Services and I can't access it on neither my web server or any other hosts on my local network. The configuration is below:

```
Site name: spoof
Application pool: spoof
Physical path: C:\inetpub\spoof
Type: http
Host name: spoof.local
IP address: 192.168.1.5
Directory browsing: Enabled
```

The following files are in C:\inetpub\spoof:

```
spoof.html
web.config
```

When I open up the browser and input 192.168.1.5 I get "page cannot be displayed".

My DNS has a standard primary forward lookup zone 'spoof.local' with the zone name 'spoof.local.dns'.

Please can somebody help me:

- Figure out how to access my website (spoof.local) on my web-server host VM
- Figure out how to access my website (spoof.local) on other VMs on my local network (I have a DNS server, web server, and windows 10 client)